# AWS EC2 Linux restrict SFTP user to their home directory when users connect from WinSCP

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, sftp, chroot, home-directory

I'm working on a solution to restrict the user to the home directory or a specific directory.

I need to restrict a user for below scenario,
we have multiple Wordpress installation in webroot `/var/www/html/wordpress1` and `/var/www/html/wordpress2`,  I need to create a user and set a new user home directory as `/var/www/html/wordpress2/wp-content` and when this new user connected with a password using WinSCP, the user should be able to access only `/var/www/html/wordpress2/wp-content` and user cannot go out of the directory.

I have followed the below steps to create a user and group and set user home directory and changed `sshd_config`  but when a user connects to the server using Winscp, user still able to access any directory on the server.

```
useradd -g sftpgroup -d /var/www/html/wordpress2/wp-content sftpuser1
sudo passwd sftpuser1
```

Modified the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
   Match Group sftpgroup
   ChrootDirectory /home
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding no
```

After the configuration, still a new user able to see all the other folders on the server.

Hope this diagram helps to understand my problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ETkg.jpg)

Can someone please help me with some solution

Answer (score 0):

If you chroot the users to `/home` and all users have their homes as subfolders of `/home`, then indeed the users can see all homes.

You probably wanted:

```
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
```

Or even better:

```
ChrootDirectory %h
```

See [`ChrootDirectory` documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory) and the [list of supported tokens](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#TOKENS).

---

Side note: You have your directives indented under `Subsystem`, what gives an impression as if they should be used for SFTP only. They won't, they are global. Actually an indentation has no meaning in `sshd_config`. All that matters is if some `Match` directives are before the directive. For that reason the directives are commonly indented after the `Match`. But that's just for human use, the SSH server does not care.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftpgroup
   ChrootDirectory %h
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Comment: If I configure the ChrootDirectory to `%h` then sftpuser1 was not able to connect to to the server using WinSCP and when I check the logs I see BROKE-PIPE error and also I want to set sftpuser1 user home directory as `/var/www/html/wordpress2/wp-content`
Can you please help me on this